# CQWP Link to List Item

Tags: content-query-web-part, list

I cant seem to get my custom CQWP to link to a list item. If i look at everything exposed in the CQWP (using the showxml trick) the only thing close is the LinkURL which takes the format http://servername/Lists/listname/1_.000 but that does work.

I could build the link myself using the ID but found it strange an actual link wasnt exposed.

David

Answer (score 1):

Im not 100% sure what you mean, if you are talking about using your own template in ItemStyle.xsl with CQWP then the template OuterTemplate.GetSafeLink from ContentQueryMain.xsl "expose" the URL. The $SafeLinkUrl variable mentioned in the other answer uses this template in all the the predefined templates in ItemStyle.xsl. Just copy and paste that one.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact problem. Set the property UseCopyUtil of content query webpart to true 
I thing the call to OuterTemplate.GetSafeLink in ContentQueryMain.xsl will only return the safe link from a Link Column data type

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the variable $SafeLinkUrl?

Answer (score 0):

try using @LinkUrl direct in your href something like:

some text

or to use $safelink create variable first

```
<xsl:variable name="SafeLinkUrl">
        <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeLink">
             <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:variable>
```

thenk you can use $safelink in your herf code.

Hope this helps